# Is it safe to delete managed object from context instead of deleting it from to-many relationship NSSet

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have an entity Order which has to-many relationship with OrderItem entity. 
In case if I want to delete one from Order. What is the best way for that? Assumnig that one OrderItem is suitable only for one Order:

1. [order deleteOrderItem:orderItem];
2. [managedObjectContext deleteObject:orderItem];

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It shouldn't matter, so long as Order's "orderItems" relationship has an inverse relationship that points back to Order.

Comment: Thanks. I've just started my first project with Core Data.